# SMBus communication not working. smbus.h is missing

Tags: centos

I'm trying to communicate with an SMBus device on CentOS 8.0.  I've installed i2c-tools and libi2c.  Doing

```
find / -name "smbus.h" 2>/dev/null
```

doesn't return any results. Running

```
i2cdump
```

doesn't work.

```
i2cdump 4 0x12 sp 
"Error: Block read failed, return code -6"
```

Command

```
i2cget
```

returns "Error: Read failed"

I tried compiling a c program myself to read from the block following [this guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/dev-interface.html) but when I try to compile it says

> "fatal error: i2c/smbus.h: No such file or directory"

```
yum whatprovides */smbus.h
```

shows some results for kernel-devel but installing that didn't help, that smbus.h file is empty.  How can I communicate with the smbus?

```
i2cdetect -l
```

shows

```
i2c-3  i2c    DPDDC-C                     I2C adapter
i2c-1  i2c    i915 gmbus dpc              I2C adapter
i2c-4  smbus  SMBus I801 adapter at f040  SMBus adapter
i2c-2  i2c    i915 gmbus misc             I2C adapter
i2c-0  i2c    i915 gmbus dpb              I2C adapter
```

**Updates after telcoM's answer**

i2cdetect -F 4 output:

```
Functionalities implemented by /dev/i2c-4: 
I2C                              no 
SMBus Quick Command              yes 
SMBus Send Byte                  yes 
SMBus Receive Byte               yes 
SMBus Write Byte                 yes 
SMBus Read Byte                  yes 
SMBus Write Word                 yes 
SMBus Read Word                  yes 
SMBus Process Call               no 
SMBus Block Write                yes 
SMBus Block Read                 yes 
SMBus Block Process Call         no 
SMBus PEC                        yes 
I2C Block Write                  yes 
I2C Block Read                   yes
```

i2cdetect 4 output:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- 08 -- -- 0b -- -- -- -- 
10: 10 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- 44 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: 50 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

**Edit 2:**
I figured out the device I'm trying to read from is 0x0b.  I can successfully do i2c dump with this:

```
i2cdump 4 0x0b
```

However this is an smbus device with error checking so the correct command should be:

```
i2cdump 4 0x0b sp
```

But I get this error with that command.

> Error: Block read failed, return code -74

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

In order to compile your own programs that use the `libi2c` library package, you'll need to install the corresponding development package also: `libi2c-devel`.

---

For both `i2cdump` and `i2cget`, it looks like you'll have to specify the bus number/name and an address on the bus to make them do anything useful.

In your case, smbus is `i2c-4` or bus number 4. By default, the tools may attempt to use  bus number 0, which is i2c rather than SMBus - and that bus may already be under control of the i915 GPU driver, which may be another reason your commands are failing.

Not all i2c/SMBus adapters support all commands. Start with `i2cdetect -F 4` to see which commands are supported by your SMBus adapter. The output will be something like this:

```
# i2cdetect -F 4
Functionalities implemented by /dev/i2c-4:
I2C                              no
SMBus Quick Command              yes
SMBus Send Byte                  yes
SMBus Receive Byte               yes
SMBus Write Byte                 yes
SMBus Read Byte                  yes
SMBus Write Word                 yes
SMBus Read Word                  yes
SMBus Process Call               no
SMBus Block Write                yes
SMBus Block Read                 yes
SMBus Block Process Call         no
SMBus PEC                        yes
I2C Block Write                  yes
I2C Block Read                   yes
```

You can also run a device detection on your bus like this:

```
# i2cdetect 4
WARNING! This program can confuse your I2C bus, cause data loss and worse!
I will probe file /dev/i2c-4.
I will probe address range 0x03-0x77.
Continue? [Y/n] 
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- 08 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- UU -- UU -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: 30 31 -- -- 34 35 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- 44 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- 51 -- 53 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

This will list the bus address values that seem to be responding to a simple command on the bus. Armed with the list of valid addresses and bus commands, you can start probing individual devices on the bus.

Comment: I couldn't find the `libi2c-devel` package for `el8`. Do you have a source please?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot seem to find it either... the naming will sometimes vary between distributions, so Debian would use `libi2c-dev` while RHEL/CentOS/Fedora might use `libi2c-devel` or `i2c-devel`, but there does not seem to be any of those for CentOS 8. Perhaps it's been merged with some other development package with a non-obvious name.

Comment: Thanks @telcoM.  I've updated my answer with the output of those commands.  I'll have to ask the manufacturer why the device at 0x12 isn't showing up.  I did expect the device at 0x10 but I can't read from it either.  I spent an hour searching for an i2c-dev package earlier today and couldn't find anything like it in CentOS 8.  I have no idea what the other devices are.

Comment: Oh, I have found it. It's in the kernel tree: `/usr/src/kernels/*/include/config/i2c/smbus.h`. So, install the kernel sources (or `-devel` packages).

Comment: @Ned64 I installed that earlier (see post) and it didn't help, still doesn't compile.  That file is actually empty!

Comment: @BakonJarser If you install the kernel package which has the file, and the compilation says "file not found" then you need to adjust the include path in your `Makefile`, use a `configure` option or whatever is the correct way in the build system. Please try and give detailed feedback by editing your question if that route fails.

Comment: @Ned64  That file is empty.  The methods I'm calling aren't in it.  I've updated the question with that info.

Comment: I got it to read something, but smbus calls still aren't working.